# Configuring Nginx and Socket.IO

Tags: http, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to configure [Nginx](http://nginx.org) to work with [Socket.IO](http://socket.io)

and I have found [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Nginx-and-Socket.io) in Socket.IO github wiki.

I have installed Nginx 1.1.10.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name socket.myserver.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
  }
}
```

Below is my Socket.io code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3030);

io.configure(function() {
        io.enable('browser client etag');
        io.set('transports', [
         'websocket','xhr-polling'
  ]);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And this is my client site code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://socket.mysite.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
          var socket = io.connect('http://socket.mysite.com');
          socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I'm confronting problem that the console shows only

```
info  - socket.io started
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

I know that it should creates some logs about "handshakes and heartbeats"

Did I configure something wrong? Or does my code have some errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your config, node is listening on port 3333, but nginx is trying to proxy_pass to port 3030.  Those need to match.

Comment: sorry, it was typo.. actually source was matched

Answer (score 0):

Try to change option **log level** (defaults to 3) to 1 or 2.

The amount of detail that the server should output to the logger.

on server-side

```
io.set('log level', 1);
```